# Join multiple tables on one specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am still new to SQL so this question might sound quite basic. I am using an Oracle database and I can only use **select**. I have 2 tables `Names` and `Worksite`.

`Names` table:

```
ID  Full name   Type
-----------------------
1   Sibelga     Company
2   Belgacom    Company
3   Brussels    Authority
4   Etterbeek   Authority
```

`Worksite` table:

```
ID Worksite CompanyID   AuthorityID
-----------------------------------
12569        1              3
4563         2              4
1589         1              4
1489         1              3
```

Basically, I want to get the full name of the `Authority` and `Company` for each worksite.

I'm trying to do a join but it only gives back the name of the `Authority` or of the `Company`. I'm trying the following query but it doesn't work, any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
select  
    ID worksite, 
    Full name, 
    Full name
from    
    Worksite
join    
    Names on worksite.companyID = names.ID
```

Comment: If the field is defined as you show it, `Full name` you have to use double quotes like `select ID, "Full name" from...`

Comment: Sorry I don't really get whatyou mean. I basically want to get the full name of the Company and Authority for each worksite. But a simple Join doesnt seam to work.

Comment: Consider changing your database design. With the design given you can mistakenly give a company an authority name and vice versa. Have two tables, one for companies, one for authorities, instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not the databse designer, I have read only access and have to extract information

Comment: So I suggest you ask the database designer to change it :-)

Comment: As you are still struggling with the query, you may want to show us the table definitions.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  So the query works when i use two table aliases but it doesnt work when I use the third one (in this case it doesnt work when i add the following column and its join: A."Full name" AS AuthorityName). SO it seams it is not accepting the fact that I am joining twice the same table

Comment: You are saying that `JOIN Names C ON C.ID = WS.CompanyID` works with `C."Full name" AS CompanyName`, but `JOIN Names A ON A.ID = WS.AuthorityID` doesn't work with `A."Full name" AS AuthorityName`? That is hard to imagine. It is common to join the same table more than once, so you *must* use table aliases. It seems strange that it works once but not twice for you. Maybe a typo somewhere? You may want to add your current query to your request above, so we see it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes it is strange I dont really understand. I can send you the query but the problem is that the column names and tables in the database are quite complex so I modified the names for the example..So i doubt it will help...

select WS.id_ws_fk,
B.usual_abrev_fr as impétrant,
E.usual_abrev_fr as GV
from osiris.osi_programmation WS
inner join osiris.osi_organization B on B.id_orga=WS.orga_owne_fk
inner join osiris.osi_organization E on E.id_orga=WS.id_gv_fk;

Comment: Your query is syntactically correct and gives me no error here on Oracle 11.2g. (Test tables: `create table osi_programmation (id_ws_fk number, orga_owne_fk number, id_gv_fk number);` and `create table osi_organization (id_orga number, usual_abrev_fr varchar2(100));`)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ok so i guess if the syntax is correct you think it's a mistake with the column names maybe?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks I managed, there was basically some non numéric vlues in a numercic column. I have filtered and it works now. Thanks

Comment: A numeric column can have no non-numeric values, it's numeric. So obviously it's a text column supposed to hold numeric values only. Seems about time your DBAs do their job and work their database design over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to get two names then you'll need to join to the table two times:

```
SELECT
    WS."ID worksite",
    C."Full name" AS CompanyName,
    A."Full name" AS AuthorityName
FROM
    Worksite AS WS
LEFT OUTER JOIN Names C ON C.ID = WS.CompanyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Names A ON A.ID = WS.AuthorityID
```

I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because you don't mention if the IDs will always be filled in or not. If they will always be there then you can use `INNER JOIN`. I'm also pretty wary of a table called, "Names". That's generally a red flag for a poorly designed database.

Comment: Thanks i will try this and see if it works. The ID's are always filled so I will try the inner join.

The letters C and A you add can be random I guess (in this case I guess you chose C for company and A for authority?

Comment: Yes, those are table aliases. They can be used to distinguish between multiple instances of the same table in a query or also just to make the code clearer or easier to write/read.

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to work. The log says that it doesnt recognise the letters I am adding. Any idea where I'm going wrong? I'm using an Oracle database

Comment: @philippe - are you sure you're using them consistently - in the select list, joins (defining the aliases), and the `on` clauses? (Also, depending on the error you actually get, check the case of your quoted identifiers matches the table definitions exactly; from what you showed it might need to be `WS."ID Worksite"` but you haven't been consistent in the question. Using quoted identifiers is also something to be wary of/avoided)

Comment: Yes I am using them consistently. It says the identifier is not valid. I'm using SQL developper and the table aliases are underlined in yellow in the join clause (i'm not sure what this means but it generally means an error)

Comment: I think that Oracle might require the `AS` term for table aliases. It's optional in SQL Server, so I've gotten into the habit of leaving it out. I'll correct my answer now.

Comment: @Tom H: No, unfortunately they are even *forbidden* in Oracle.

Comment: @philippe: Oracle usually tells you which identifier is not valid, e.g. `ORA-00904: C."Full name": invalid identifier`. So look at the table Names (which you call C here) and check if there is a column named `Full Name`. As Alex Poole has pointed out already, it is a bad idea to use space in column names, so that you need quotes for the columns and then upper/lower case must match the column definition. Use simple names such as `full_name` instead. Then you don't have to use quotes and don't have to care about upper/lower case.

Comment: I confirm the AS does not seem to work for Oracle. Any other ideas?

Comment: it also says this: invalid number: ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Comment: @philippe: You get this error when you treat a column as numeric, but it has non-numeric values. In above select that would happen if the company/authority ID in one of the tables were numeric and in the other it were a string containing non-numeric characters, too.

Comment: @philippe: just leave the `AS` keyword out. The table alias works without it.

Comment: @philippe: Yes, table aliases are Standard SQL and they are needed here. Only don't use `AS` for table aliases, because Oracle doesn't allow this keyword here.

Comment: So the query works when i use two table aliases but it doesnt work when I use the third one (in this case  A."Full name" AS AuthorityName). SO it seams it is not accepting the fact that I am joining twice the same table....

Comment: @philippe - what does "doesn't work" mean - what error do you get? Without the spurious `AS` keywords for the table aliases, and possibly adjusting the case of some of the columns, this query works. So you have adapted it incorrectly - but we can't see what you have done.

Comment: I've removed the previously added `AS` keywords from my answer due to the many responses saying that they are not allowed in Oracle.